Run SQL Stored Procedure to GET Data with Logic App
I am trying to create a C# program to call my Azure Logic app that calls a SQL Server stored procedure which grabs data from a table. I have my logic app working, I trigger it from the Azure side and it returns the data I want.

But triggering it from the code side is causing problems. I would think it would be a GET since I am getting data so I have tried
var response = await _client.GetAsync("LogicAppURL");

My function is set up as follows so I can trigger it too
[FunctionName("RunLogicApp")]
public async Task RunAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "RunLogicApp")] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    // ....
}

But Azure is failing coming back and saying that it is expecting a POST to run this Logic App. So I tried a PostAsync and I can only get a response code of 200 back.
Which side do I need to fix, C# code or Logic App?
My stored procedure is just a select id, email, value from table

Does your Logic App have a HTTP Response that returns the data from the stored procedure?

I have added and removed the response from the logic app because it does not seem to reach it. I have changed the status code its suppose to send but it always sends 200. Do you recommend adding it?

You must have a Response if you want to return something.  How is the response setup, did you set the return body to have the stored procedure activity output?  You probably need to show more of your logic app because we don't see the Response activity.  You should be able to test the logic app with something like Postman to verify it is returning what you want.


Which side do I need to fix, C# code or Logic App?

To get data from Logic app by calling from c# code, follow below procedure:
Design of Logic App:

body('Execute_stored_procedure_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1']

Then the c# code:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
namespace FunctionApp150
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RunAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            var rithmock = new StringContent("{}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            using var rith_httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var rithcl = await rith_httpClient.PostAsync("https://prod-16.eastus.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/be1cd/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=aW9E6zJ6V1LbWAR5w", rithmock);
            var rith_proc_res = await rithcl.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(rith_proc_res);
            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        }
    }
}

Output:

Logic app(Code called Logic app and logic app returned response):


I hope this solution will give you with a very mimimal chnage to you existing implementation. A somple change needs to done in the Logic App to address this issue I guess.
When you add a Http Request as default trigger using Old Logic App Designer the request verb will be POST by default but don't know that this can be chnaged.
You can change this to GET method by doing the following in OLD Logic App Designer

Select All new Parameter in the Logic App Http Action


Select GET verb in the combobox and save it



Now your Logic App default method will be GET.
When you run this logic app and go to Run-history you will see it has used GET verb


Logic App HTTP Triggers require the POST verb. You will also likely need a SAS token, which you can get by clicking on the trigger in the Logic App. This is tacked on to the URL as a sig query parameter.
https://yourlogicappuri/yourapp?sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

That is what I have in my ("LogicAppURL").

@Owen OK. You said you were using GET though. Try POST.

When I try a POST, the response I get is only a 200 there is no other data when it comes back. What should be my HTTPContent since I am not sending anything in my post
await _client.PostAsync(LogicAppURL, HTTPContent));

@Owen I get the feeling you are looking for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-webhook?tabs=standard
I could be wrong but I do not think the HTTP request trigger is capable of returning data, other than the 200/202 indicating that the request is accepted.

@KonTheCat It will return data except in a few rare known cases.

@Owen you said it works from a browser in the LA. Press F12 to open dev tools, enable network capture, test in browser again and inspect the request Headers, and response body. Is there data in the response? Is it a post? Are there any Headers in the request you're missing? Are you trying to call your function  which then calls the LA?
